# Application.dataPath doesn't give the right path

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good day, I feel like Application,.dataPath is useless unless you are doing it on Editor, I built my application on Windows and Mac, both says that my file is not found. But when I do it on Editor everything is okay. I'm trying to load a JSON file from my Assets root folder. What is the best way to load my JSON File as a FILE, not get its content and read it.

```
SomeClass.SomeMethod(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "jsonFile.json")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.dataPath is the path to your [assets folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html).

This path is only available on Editor, not in build. If you want something that works in both sides, Editor and Build, should be done inside the folder [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html).